# Find the time complexity of the given negative recurrence relation

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, relation, recurrence

what will be the time complexity of recurrence relation
**`T(n) = T(n-3) + T(n-2) - T(n-1) if n>3`** otherwise **`T(n)=n`**

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your `T` can represent a time complexity since many of its values are negative. I assume your question is actually "what is the complexity of `T`".

The solution to your recurrence relation, for n>3 is `T(n) = n` if `n` is odd, `4-n` if `n` is even.

The induction is easy: for even `n`

```
T(n) = T(n-3) + T(n-2) - T(n-1)
     = n-3 + 4-(n-2) - (n-1)
     = 4 - n
```

For `n` odd:

```
T(n) = T(n-3) + T(n-2) - T(n-1)
     = 4-(n-3) + n-2 - (4 - (n-1))
     = 4 - n + 3 + n - 2 - 4 + n - 1
     = n
```

And the base case needs checking for `T(4), T(5), T(6)`, which are `0, 5, -2` respectively.

Thus T(n) = O(n).